# adb shell,how can i get request back from this?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make program which just check if phone is rooted or not.For this I have to send adb shell `su` via cmd,but problem is my textbox not getting any output to check results..
Here is  my code :

```
public string root_checker
    {
        get
        {
            psi.Arguments = "shell su";
            Process call = Process.Start(psi);
            StreamReader sr = call.StandardOutput;
            string output = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return output;
        }


    }
```

this one in button:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string shell = adb.root_checker;
            textBox1.Text = shell;
        }
```

my program just became not responding  and nothing happened,I searched lot on internet but got nothing useful.

Thank You

Comment: `getter` should be returning value. This won't compile. Are you sure, this is actual code? Also `StreamReader` is disposable. You should be disposing it to clean-up un-managed resources.

Comment: sorry for my mistake,post corrected now..